# How to set vuetify drawer menu permanent when the devices is computer and no permanant when the device is mobile

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

someone can help to set my drawer menu permanent depending of the user device ?
I was thinking of using the vuetify grid system to find out if I'm in lg or md or sm, but I don't know how to do it.

This is my drawer menu code :

```js
<v-navigation-drawer
            @input="updateDrawer"
            :hide-overlay="true"
            :mini-variant="true"
            :expand-on-hover="true"
            :touchless="true"
            :disable-resize-watcher="false"
            style="min-width: 100px!important;"
            v-model="d"
            //here set this: :permanent="!isMobile"
            app
            clipped
    >
        ...

    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, You can bind permanent directly to the breakpoint, instead of computed.

```
:permanent="!$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly"
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank . I think this is the simple solution. I take it

Comment: Not at all, glad to help.

Comment: Love this one. Also: ```:permanent="!$vuetify.breakpoint.sm && !$vuetify.breakpoint.xs"```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to still allow manual toggling of the navigation drawer (using a hamburger button), you could add another computed property for the v-model. This allows the drawer to auto show/hide based on the breakpoint *or* be manually toggled...

```
  computed: {
    isLarge() {
        return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name !== 'xs'
    },
    showDrawer() {
        return this.isLarge || this.drawer
    }
  }, 


<v-navigation-drawer 
      v-model="showDrawer"
      :permanent="isLarge"
      color="primary"
      absolute 
      dark>..
</<v-navigation-drawer>
```

https://codeply.com/p/Y883gzgiKe

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that works for my case. I publish in case someone wants to do the same thing as me.

vuetify can give you the user device screen size basing on grid sysmtem. To get the sreen size, do it when the component is computed.

```js
       computed: {
            isComputer() {
                return this.$vuetify.breakpoint.name !== 'xs';
            }
        }
```

The drawer menu code can be updated with this:

```
   <v-navigation-drawer
            ...
            //listen if it's a computer(in my case i want md, lg, sm as computer)
            :permanent="isComputer"
            app
            clipped
    ></v-navigation-drawer>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didnt work for me. If you are facing the same issue try:

```
:permanent="!$vuetify.display.xs"
```